# Whats the point of a move-constructor taking a constans rvalue?

Tags: c++11, rvalue, move-constructor

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor; *"A class can have multiple move constructors, e.g. both `T::T(const T&&)` and `T::T(T&&)`"*

When would one want to pass a constant rvalue to the move-constructor?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "never".

However, you can indeed write a function like this:

```
Foo const f();
```

Now something like `Foo x = f();` would use the `Foo const &&` constructor if it is available. But it will also bind to the `Foo const &` constructor with pleasure, and since both references are constant, there's really no need for the rvalue version.

In particular, there's mothing "move" about that constructor, since, as we established, the reference is constant.

Comment: to be pedantic, the fact that the reference is to const doesn't prevent you from moving some `mutable` resource. (and, of course, it's still called 'move constructor' in 12.8/3 even when taking `const X&&`)